# Can't Find Chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting

Tags: google-chrome

I can't find this feature. Somebody knows why? If this feature is unavailable then please suggest me another one or any script to mute youtube sound from the browse Tab.

Comment: chrome://flags/#enable-media-session-service and chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling is not working for me! @edu

Comment: First time enabled and restarted, nothing happened. After that disabled and restart the browser, also nothing happened. @edu